# Peek stack in python 3

Tags: python

Question: Implement peek(stack) that returns, but doesn't remove, the top element from a stack. Return None if list is empty.

I tried many times but did not successfully get it, anyone can help?

My attempt:

```
def peek_stack(stack):
    if stack == []:
        return None
    else:
        s= stack.copy()
        return s.pop(0)
```

Comment: Your issue is that `s` is pointer to `stack` so it is a shallow copy not a deep copy which is what you want

Comment: Why not just return `stack[0]`?

Comment: Python `list`s can already be used as stacks.  `lst.append` is push, `lst[-1]` is peek, `lst.pop()` is... pop.  [Relevant docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#using-lists-as-stacks)

Comment: In general, it would be better to raise an exception in the event of an empty stack.

Comment: actually, you should use your_stack[-1], because you want to always return the last element in your stack without popping it

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you need to use your way to solve this, please use `return s.pop()` rather than `return s.pop(0)`, because `s.pop()` will pop up the last element, but `s.pop(0)` will pop up the first element...

And by the way, it's recommend just implement it like this(it can avoid copy your stack, and improve performance)

```
def peek_stack(stack):
    if stack:
        return stack[-1]    # this will get the last element of stack
    else:
        return None
```

Answer (score 11):

Simpler one:

```
def peek_stack(stack):
    if stack:
        return stack[-1]
```

Comment: from [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations): Be consistent in `return` statements. Either all `return` statements in a function should return an expression, or none of them should. If any `return` statement returns an expression, any `return` statements where no value is returned should explicitly state this as `return None`, and an explicit `return` statement should be present at the end of the function (if reachable).

Answer (score 0):

```
def peek(stk):
    if stk == []:
        return None
    else:
        top = len(stk) - 1
        return stk[top]
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please include a brief explanation of what the code does and how it helps solving the problem in the question.

Comment: ..and keywords def, if, else, return should not be capitalized.

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also include an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: While this post may answer the question, code-only answers are often considered low-quality. Please provide some rationale / text explanation as to why this is the correct answer, even if short.

Comment: use negative index `stk[-1]` instead of  `len(stk)-1`